# Using Infopath forms and Sharepoint List forms on the same list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-services, sharepoint-library, infopath-data-connections

I created an Infopath form to allow customers to submit data to a Sharepoint 2013 List.  Is it possible to still use the Sharepoint List forms to view the information that was updated on the list by the Infopath form?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, that cannot be done as you want to use InfoPath form for editing and use the default form for viewing.